# How to protect from mass assignment for models in has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

There are user and user_position in our rails 3.1.4 app. A user has many user_positions and a user_position belongs to a user. In user model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_positions, :allow_destroy => true
validates_presence_of :user_positions
```

When a user is saved, the user_positions is automatically saved as well. In order to autosave user_positions, most fields in user and user_positions have to be declared as `attr_accessible`. Here is the `attr_accessible` in user model:

```
attr_accessible :name, :login, :password_confirmation, :password, :user_positions_attributes
```

Here is what in user_position model:

```
  belongs_to :user 
  attr_accessible :position  
  validates :position, :presence => true
```

As you can see, all the fields here are open to mass assignment. `:as => :admin` seems not working well here. How to protect those fields? Thanks so much.

Comment: What is stored in user_positions?

Comment: just position which is a string.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set password and other vulnerable fields as attr_accessible if you don't change them in the same call. So, this should work:

```
user.user_positions.first.position = "some update"
user.save
```

If you're saving fails on validation, then it's the problem of the save action, that for some reason updates the password. So, if it persists, paste it here.

Comment: We want to take advantage of autosave in rails association for the child user_position object along with the saving of user object. When a new user is created, the admin enters the password and such so it would be convenient to mass assign by making them attr_accessible .

Comment: If you want to assign the password in the same controller method, you either have to mark it as attr_accessible, or do it in a separate method call, like: `user.password = params[:password]` or `user.update_attribute(password, params[:password])` – depending on the logic needed.

Answer (score 0):

What we did was to add the same security role :admin to attr_accessible in both user and user_position model. The change allows us to create and update user info. Does it provide the security against unwanted mass assignment? It seems does. But we did not test and verify it.